# Error al instalar cli de ember en Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, npm, ember-cli

Alguien sabe por que no me deja instalar

> npm install -g ember-cli

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no pegues imágenes. Son difíciles de leer desde dispositivos móviles.

Comment: "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te dice que no tiene permisos para crear carpetas, como así también menciona una posible solución:

> Ejecutar el comando en modo root/administrador

Lo que debes hacer es abrir la consola de comandos (`cmd`) en modo administrador. Así puedes hacerlo:

- Presiona la tecla Windows del teclado para que aparezca el menú Inicio (o haz clic en Inicio)
- Escribe “cmd” en la barra de búsqueda.
- Has clic derecho sobre el programa y elige la opción `Ejecudar como administrador`

Ejemplo `Windows 10`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya le intente de ese modo y me sigue apareciendo los mismos errores y tambien tengo control total en la carpeta

Comment: Me instala cualquier npm pero el de ember no quiere instalar

Comment: @Eduard, existe un problema de permisos en [este directorio](https://ibb.co/iqsSvv). Si es verdad que tienen permisos, ve al directorio y prueba borrandolo, esto también deberia solucionar el problema.

Comment: Ya la borre, lo que no entiendo es por que me deja instalar por ejemplo npm install -g stylus y el de ember no me deja.

Comment: Era el antivirus que estaba bloqueado al crear las carpetas